# how to create custom chart in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to create chart like this that has a circular border
[image]

i want to create custom like this/
how i am gonna do that , is there any packages that i can modify it and make it like this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a chart, you can use [syncfusion_flutter_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts)

and if you want create curves you can use `CustomPaint` widget. one example I find in my code for you:

```
CustomPaint(
   painter: CurveBackground(color: \\ yourColor),
   child: \\ your child
)


class CurveBackground extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;

  CurveBackground({this.color});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = color;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, Dimens.size_30());
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.4, size.height * 0.1,
        size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.3);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.6,
        size.width * 0.45, size.height * 0.7);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 1, size.height * 0.9, size.width * 0.9, size.height * 1.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: what part of that package can i use?

Comment: you're right. I saw some numbers in your photo and thought it was a chart! I updated my post :)

Comment: well i want to create a chart

Comment: but i want to customize it like that

Comment: So why did you give me a negative score? 1. this package is open source "https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-widgets" 2. your chart is something like ***"Spline Area"***

Comment: i did not i can't it needs to have 125 reputation to give a negative rate